# Select a range name - 'DisplayName' from a given table if it exist in the range, defined in table for a given number

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

For a given temp table structure is as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    DisplayName VARCHAR(50),
    Value1 VARCHAR(50),
    Value2 VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES
('569-580','569','580')
('581-592','581','592')
('593-607','593','607')
('608-620','608','620')

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

I need get DisplayName if user provide a number then that number exists in that range like
if given number is 606 then output should be:
'593-607'
if given number is 608 then output should be:
'608-620'

Comment: Love to see what you have tried

Comment: Why is `Value1` and `Value2` declared as `varchar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @GivenNumber INT = 606
SELECT DisplayName
FROM #TempTable1
WHERE @GivenNumber BETWEEN CAST(Value1 AS INT) AND CAST(Value2 AS INT)
```